# Restrict the NACL to the cidr range of the vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc, terraform-provider-aws

I am new to terraform and was reading more to understand it. I was reading the section 
[Resource: aws_default_network_acl] (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/default_network_acl.html)
I came across this example;

```
resource "aws_default_network_acl" "default" {
  default_network_acl_id = aws_vpc.mainvpc.default_network_acl_id

  ingress {
    protocol   = -1
    rule_no    = 100
    action     = "allow"
    cidr_block = aws_vpc.mainvpc.cidr_block
    from_port  = 0
    to_port    = 0
  }
}
```

What i would like to know is why would you restrict the ingress rule to the cidr range of the vpc?
Would that mean that your ip address will have to fall within the cidr block range in order to gain access to the vpc. 
My ip address: 10.19.178.104. VPC cidr block: 10.19.178.100/24. 
Am i correct in saying that since my ip address falls within the given cidr range, the NACL  will accept traffic from my ip?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? NACLs are tricky as they are stateless. Modifying ingress usually means you have to adjust egress rules as well. For most use cases using default NACLs should be enough. You can control IP ranges using Security Groups which are statefull.

Comment: *"My ip address: 10.19.178.104..."*  Your IP address is not and cannot be 10.19.178.104, and 10.19.178.100/24 is not a valid CIDR block, so it isn't clear what scenario you are intending to establish with these assertions.

Comment: the ip address is a fake. I am only doing it to give an example that is my why. My use case is to limit the range of ips from 0.0.0.0/0 where the internet gateway is normally routed to my own ip address but some have advise me that it is better to use the nacl for this limit the range of ip address so that you can only accept traffic from your company's ip ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some business models do not require outbound internet access, therefore restricting the NACL to allow inbound/outbound only a trusted CIDR range would help to meet these requirements.

NACLs are bound at the subnet level, so it might be that private subnets are entirely restricted to only communicating with resources within the VPC.

This is just one rule, assuming their no rules with a number lower than 100 that would deny specific traffic then you would be correct that your IP would be allowed.